# How to upload video to youtube with chunked stream using data api

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

First let me explain my goal,

I am downloading a video as stream from different sources like Local, S3, Drive or Mega also with buffer and stream i want to upload that video with chunk of 256KB which is least that google wants, i am getting the first 256KB chunk and save it to MemoryBuffer, then when i upload it, it uploads immediately without waiting other chunks, I don't know how to solve this. here is my code.

```cs
    var video = new Video();
    video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
    video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
    video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
    video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
    video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22";
    video.Status = new VideoStatus();
    video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted";

    var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", stream, "video/*");
    videosInsertRequest.ChunkSize = ResumableUpload.MinimumChunkSize;

    videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += (progress) =>
    {
      switch (progress.Status)
      {
        case UploadStatus.Starting:
          Console.WriteLine("Starting to upload.");
          break;
        case UploadStatus.Uploading:
          Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
          break;
        case UploadStatus.Completed:
          Console.WriteLine("Uploaded.");
          break;
        case UploadStatus.Failed:
          Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
          break;
      }
    };

    return videosInsertRequest;
```

```cs
    var stream = Mega.Download(video);

    int bufferSize = 1024 * 256;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int bufferPosition = 0;

    Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer);

    var youtubeVideo = Uploader.YouTube(memoryStream); //this is the code above

    bool isEnd = false;
    while (isEnd is false)
    {
      while (bufferPosition < bufferSize && isEnd is false)
      {
        var readBytes = await stream.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, bufferPosition, bufferSize - bufferPosition);
        bufferPosition += readBytes;
        isEnd = readBytes == 0;
      }

      await memoryStream.FlushAsync();
      memoryStream.Position = 0;
      await memoryStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bufferPosition);

      await youtubeVideo.UploadAsync();

      Array.Clear(buffer);
      bufferPosition = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Found a solution? Also looking for doing the same

Comment: sadly no. i couldn't find any solution.